# What is an attenuated virus? What is done to it?

Tags: virology

UPDATE: So it looks like I've asked a complex and technical question. I'm going to take @tyersome's advice and study [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/human-biology#immunology) on immunology, and from there, formulate a better question if I still need to.

---

The question is based on the idea that often a vaccine is based on an attenuated virus.

My understanding is that a virus isn't really alive in the same way a bacterium is, which means they can't be killed. (Correct?)

My (layman) understanding is that a virus is simply DNA or RNA wrapped in a thin layer of protein. (So is it a lifeform, or merely an extremely complex set of molecules?)

I can imagine it's possible, chemically, to obliterate the molecular structure of a virus, and thus "kill" it, but would such a "debris soup" be useful in a vaccine?

I'm not asking how a virus is attenuated, ie, by growing it in certain cultures. I'm asking what it actually means for a virus to be "attenuated"? What's different about it, yet still makes it usable as a method to teach the immune system?

Comment: The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: @tyersome  Well, everything that came up when I googled described various techniques as to HOW a virus is attenuated. But nothing in layman's terms as to what it actually means for a virus to be "attenuated", except "less virulent."  So why is it attenuated and not, say, just a different strain or variant by that time?

Comment: What is the distinction you are trying to make between "attenuated" and "different strain or variant"? Have you read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuated_vaccine)? ——— You seem to have *multiple questions* some of which (especially the last) are much *too broad* to be answered here. (Both of these are also criteria for closing questions.) ——— To really understand this take/read an introduction to immunology and then post any questions you still have. I have found [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/human-biology#immunology) a good introduction.

Comment: Presumably, attenuated means it can't replicate.

Comment: @DKNguyen - not necessarily, it may be able to enter and replicate part of the virion, but not the whole genome or perhaps has a packaging defect. Polio and MMR vaccines are both attenuated. The polio one in particular is known to occasionally cause infection and be passed on to others.

Comment: @Stewart - you can edit your post with the things that you have found out about how attenuation is done and how this helps make it less pathogenic. Note that the exact mechanisms are specific to the type of virus. Killed (inactivated) vaccines have the structures preserved by fixation or by chemically damaging the genome so that it no longer functions, but proteins remain intact.

Comment: @tyersome Thanks for that top tip on Khan Academy

Comment: @DKNguyen  That would be a clear well-defined distinction. If factual, that would be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @bob1 What I found about HOW attenuation is done were long, varied descriptions. None of them went on to explain what actually happens to the virus itself to make it less pathogenic, yet still workable for immune system response.

Comment: @Stewart - that's because what happens to the virus is specific to the group of viruses - so changes in an influenza would be different to a coronavirus for example.

Comment: @bob1  OK. That sounds like the beginnings of an answer. Does that imply that the functional definition of "attenuated" is different for each group?  And that "attenuated" is therefore a colloquialism for the layman?

Comment: Lower entry/binding to receptor, lower replication, lower pathogenicity, sometimes missing proteins or parts of it, and with genetic engineering more curious changes such as lesser replication fidelity, sub-optimal TRS, some proteins replaced by other ones (influenza reassortant). Historically it was just about finding a closely related virus circulating in a different species, giving fewer symptoms and cross-protection (vaccinia virus). Then it was about selecting passaged viruses giving fewer plaques in lab, adapting to eggs so that after enough passages it replicates poorly in human cells.

Comment: @Stewart As reuns notes, "attenuated" doesn't really have a technical definition, it just means giving fewer or less severe symptoms while still provoking an immune reaction that will provide protection against the strain(s) of interest.